# My div show/ hide code works fine on a static HTML page but doesn't work on a Wordpress 3.5.1 page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

This is sort of a condensed version of the code, the real version is too long to post but this is enough to represent the concept. I am using this to switch guitar diagrams based on several choices represented by anchors with the corresponding id in the href="". After spending several days getting it to work just right on a static html page, the script won't work in a Wordpress page which is where I intend to use it. I have tried it with the script in the head or inline (which shouldn't matter) - but either way it will not function. I know that Wordpress and certain plugins use Jquery so there may be a version mismatch causing conflicts. I am not (yet) an expert in javascript but I know there are several ways to skin a cat as the saying goes, I just need to find one that plays nice with Wordpress. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var divswitch = $('div.diagram_container a');

    divswitch.bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);
        var ids = divswitch.each(function(){
           $($(this).attr('href')).hide();   
        });
        $($anchor.attr('href')).show();
        event.preventDefault();
    });


});
</script>

<style>
.diagram {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.diagram_container {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>

    <div id="RH_RW_Div" class="diagram_container" style="float:left; display:block;">
        <div class="diagram_menu">
          <a class="checked" href="#RH_RW_Div"><span class="checkbox_label">Right Handed</span></a> 
          <a class="unchecked" href="#LH_RW_Div"><span class="checkbox_label">Left Handed</span></a>
        </div>
        <img class="diagram" src='images/RH_RW.gif' /><br />
    </div>

    <div id="LH_RW_Div" class="diagram_container" style="float:left; display:none;">
        <div class="diagram_menu">
          <a class="unchecked" href="#RH_RW_Div"><span class="checkbox_label">Right Handed</span></a> 
          <a class="checked" href="#LH_RW_Div"><span class="checkbox_label">Left Handed</span></a>
        </div>
        <img class="diagram" src='images/LH_RW.gif' /><br />
    </div>
```

Comment: What does the `console` say?

Comment: SyntaxError: syntax error
[Break On This Error]  

$(document).ready(function() {</p>

Comment: Wordpress is adding <p> tags, going to eliminate spaces in the script and see if that helps...

Comment: I don't spot any syntax error in the code you posted, perhaps it is the way the full code is written? Is there an accessible version of your work in progress that I could check? If not, check very well your JS syntax.

Comment: Ah! You have posted the script in the post content? You shouldn't have any problem if you post it in the HTML version of the editor. But you should never post JS on the post editor, by the way.

Comment: I put it back in the head, was just testing it inline...

Comment: Console says:   TypeError: $ is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

$(document).ready(function() {

Comment: Use this syntax: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){});`, `$` is not yet defined.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH  Sunyatasattva !!!!!    That did it. You have saved me hours of further testing and retesting. I just don't get why it worked on a static HTML page to begin with....

Comment: Please check my answer for that: it worked on the static HTML because `jQuery.noConflict()` is not run by default, giving you access immediately to the `$` variable. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress uses by default [**jQuery.noConflict()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). This is to assure that there is no conflict by other libraries using the `$` variable. That's why your console says it's not a function.

However, obviously, the `jQuery` variable still works, and you should use that, and passing to your function the `$` variable yourself to enable the shorthand version of `jQuery`.

So your code should look like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

     // Your functions go here

});
```

Comment: @  Sunyatasattva - Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: No problem, here to help :)

Comment: I will post the URL of the guitar site with the code above when I get it looking more respectable. If you are inclined to, check out http://destinyhacker.com/  I am using this site to further test some social network style code I have been working on. The videos and discussion are fairly intellectual/ philosophical. I would love to have another intellectual on board. cheers!...

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your Wordpress install or a plugin is already loading up jQuery in the head. Check to see if it exists there, and if it does, don't call it again.

If that doesn't do it and you have this site online, send me the link and I'll take a look.

Calling jQuery twice will often lead to problems. There is also a proper way to load jQuery and override the Wordpress version if you specifically need 1.8.3 ([wp_register_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)), but I don't think you need to go down that route yet.

Comment: @Sunyatasattva's comment above is the ticket (I can't comment directly there due to my reputation) - must be putting the script in the wysiwyg editor.

Comment: No I only use HTML view so that could not be it. Script is back in the head now and still breaking. console says     TypeError: $ is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

$(document).ready(function() {

Comment: I see. So is jQuery being called twice in the head?